# How much of load can LokiJs handle

Tags: embedded-javascript, lokijs

I am planning to use lokijs with a node server. I am not sure how much of the load can it handle in coparison with mongodb?

I would like to know how smooth can it run with 100000 documents in it?

Thanks
Vasanth

Comment: I'm the author of LokiJS. Benchmarks of this type have not been performed yet as mostly LokiJS is being used on client side (despite the fact that I love the idea of Loki on the server). I don't see 100k documents being too problematic to handle, but if you are willing to give it a go it would be awesome. Please feel free to contact me if you want to report results / help

Comment: I am very curious regarding the OPs progress with this.

Answer (score 1):

I am mid flow an app where I have about 7 collection and 60 + million docs combined ... so yes 100000 is fine, but will vary on doc size I suppose.